# How to perform a XERO API query within MAKE.com

Tags: loops, make.com, gsheets, xero

Using MAKE.com, I need to feed a given Google Sheets with a table, where rows represent Journal Lines in Manual Journals from XERO. However, I only need Journal Lines associated to a given set of accounts, say SET_OF_ACCOUNTS. My XERO instance contains 10+ organisations and I will need to fetch Journal Line details from all these Xero organisations.

My current idea is to:

1 - Establish a Xero connection with MAKE.com's Xero Module
2 - Loop over the Xero organisations and use the GET method on Manual Journals
3 - Loop over the fetched Manual Journals using their IDs and use the GET a Manual Journal method on each Manual Journal.
4 - Extract all Journal Lines from the Manual Journal, and exclude Journal Lines not associated to an account in SET_OF_ACCOUNTS
5 - Loop over the remaining Journal Lines and for each, insert a row to my pre-existing Google Sheets, whereby columns represent attributes of Journal Lines.

**What is an efficient way of implementing this procedure within MAKE.com so that the MAKE.com scenario does not take too much time to run and consumes not too many scenario operations? **

I am still stuck on step 1.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding point 2:**

If you build this solution in Make it will consume a minimum of 1 operation per journal, which could consume a considerable amount of operations. There is no way around this within Make. If you are concerned about the cost this would incur, then I would recommend looking into building this on another low-code platform like n8n.io as in the case of this scenario it would be more cost effective than Make.

**Regarding point 1:**

Make sure you are using the [Xero modules in Make](https://www.help.make.com/en/help/app/xero). Setting up the connection is fairly straightforward. If you run into any issues make sure your user has sufficient permissions on Xero itself, you could also try clearing your cache for make and xero sites.

Hope this helps.